# OWIN Configuration Without Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-identity

I Plan to use `AspNet Identity` through `WCF` Service without using `EntityFramework`. Thus i have created `IUser` and `IUserStore` Implementations.

But `Startup.Auth` has the following line which expects a `DbContext` which i dont have.

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create); // What to Do Here ?
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

How should i configure it without a DbContext ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you plan to store the users and roles?

Comment: @RichardMosselveld It is in my DAL which is accessed through WCF Service. I plan to use Service client methods in my IUserStore Implementation.

Comment: Do you get any exception after removing that line? It is not really necessary to have if you did remove all depedencies to the DbContext. I mean there should not be a statement of retrieving the DbContext from the OwinContext anymore.

Comment: Check what this extension method does (the code is open source) and find out what you need to do in your scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason to have `app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create)` is to be able to resolve `DbContext` when it is required for `ApplicationUserManager`. And if you are not using EF for this, then it is safe to remove that line.

However, `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` is required by the framework if you are doing cookie invalidation when `SecurityStamp` is updated; or if you are resolving `ApplicationUserManager` from OWIN context: `context.Get<ApplicationUserManager>()`.